# Traduction de "ice shelf" comparé à "sea ice"

Tags: terminologie

Le mot français "banquise" décrit n'importe quelle couche de glace sur la mer là où l'anglais a deux mots: "ice shelf" quand la glace vient d'un glacier qui descend sur la mer et "sea ice" pour la glace qui se forme quand l'eau de mer gèle. Existe-t'il un équivalent de cette dichotomie en français?

Answer (score 1):

La profonde couverture de glace des pôles est appelée une **calotte glaciaire** ([encyclopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banquise)). Cet article nous dit qu'il ne faut pas confondre ce terme avec le terme "**banquise**", celui-ci étant utilisé pour les couches de glace formées à la surface. Ceci correspond bien avec la définition du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/banquise).

- A.− GÉOGR. PHYS. et GÉOL. Banc de glace d'épaisseur variable, formé par congélation de l'eau de mer, qui borde le rivage des régions polaires

On voit cependant dans cette entrée du TLFi que par extension "banquise" signifie "amas de glace" ce qui expliquerait que "banquise" puisse être utilisé pour nommer une calotte glaciaire. Cependant le terme  sans  équivoque c'est "calotte glaciaire" ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/calotte)), le terme qui est utilisé dans un contexte scientifique ou didactique.

- 3. GÉOL. Calotte glaciaire, polaire. Glacier très étendu et très épais, dont la surface est légèrement convexe et recouvre ou déborde la plupart des reliefs`` (George 1970).

Il existe donc bien deux termes aussi en français.

La "**glace de mer**" ou "**glace marine**" est un terme non équivoque pour "banquise" (sea ice but also ice formations in rivers and lakes).